# Maximum call stack exceeded trying to set date in paper-date-picker

Tags: javascript, date, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

With https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker (based on moment.js)
I am trying to set the date (optionally) *offset* months in the future.

The element:

```
<paper-date-picker date="{{date}}"></paper-date-picker>
```

The following property works:

```
properties: {
    date: {
        type: Date
    }
}
```

But this floods the console with "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." from polymer:1258 & polymer-mini:964

```
properties: {
    date: {
        type: Date,
        value: function() {
          var myDate = new Date();
          var offset = this.attributes.offset ? parseInt(this.attributes.offset.value) : 0;
            myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + offset);
            return myDate;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter what the date transform is, if the "value" block is there it fails.
Logging the values in the function shows the above parses date as I'd expect, but I guess my expectations differ from the component?

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Note that if you add 1 month to 31 May per the above you'll get 1 July (similarly for other cases where adding a month ends on a date that doesn't exist).

Comment: io41, have you found a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the date of the calendar object rather than the date-picker object, e.g. `this.$.datepicker-id.$.calendar.date = new Date();`

That worked in terms of resetting the date for the picker, but I actually encountered a different issue afterwards related to not being able to reselect the same date that I previously selected after closing the dialog. I had to remove the logic in `calendar._updateSelection` to not set the `selected.width` to `0px`.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the error by plugging in a `new Date()` (as reported in console):

```
<paper-date-picker date="Tue Mar 15 2016 17:32:36 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"></paper-date-picker>
```

So even though this is a valid datetime, I guess the date picker is not happy about the format of `myDate` for one reason or another. I think you should try converting that date to a string in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`. As a quick proof-of-concept, try:

```
properties: {
    date: {
        type: Date,
        value: function() {          
            return '03/15/2016';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with using date methods to build a string as you suggested and got "Invalid date: 15/03/2016 paper-calendar.html:591"


So I hard coded that String as a return value (updating the property type to String as well) and the same. Although it works if the component property is set in HTML to date="15/03/2016" instead of date="{{date}}".


My first example does seem to work, {{date}} has an observer to a function that updates a formatted version and I can see both change if they're monitored on the page (<p>{{date}}</p><p{{formattedDate}}</p>)


It just throws errors and jams up the browser

Comment: Note that the string needs to be in American date format.